# How to send temp data from Partial View to its parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to send temp data from Partial View to its parent View? I need information about success save to database. Please example with TempData or HttpContext.Items. Problem is how to send information about success save between difference View (From partial View to parent View)

This is method in Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult _AddPost(int idOrder, AddPositionViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var findOrder = db.Order.Find(idOrder);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                OrderPosition position = new OrderPosition { Description = viewModel.Description };
                db.OrderPosition.Add(position);
                //db.Entry(position).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                findOrder.OrderPositionList.Add(position);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Information = position;                  

                if (ViewBag.Information != null)
                {
                    TempData["Add-Post"] = string.Format("Odpowiedz użytkownika {0} została dodana!", User.Identity.Name);
                    //HttpContext.Items["Info"] = string.Format("Odpowiedz użytkownika {0} została dodana!", User.Identity.Name);
                }

            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return PartialView();

        }

//Method Parent View

 public ActionResult ListOrder(int? IdStatusOrder)
        {
            var ListAllOrder = db.Order.ToList();
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var viewodel = new ListOrdersUserViewModel()
            {           
                ListOrdersUser = ListOrders
            };
              };
            return View(viewodel);
        }
```

And View in MVC

```
@model AplikacjaHelpDesk.ViewModels.ListOrdersUserViewModel
@using AplikacjaHelpDesk.Infrastructure
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Orders Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdministracja.cshtml";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Layout/Home.png" />
    <a href="link">
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
    </a>
    <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp<strong>List Orders </strong></h2>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divLoading" class="panel panel-primary text-center text-primary" style="display:none;">
        <h3><strong>Please wait for post!</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="divLoadingForm" class="panel panel-primary text-center text-primary" style="display:none;">
        <h3><strong>Please wait for form</strong></h3>
    </div>
    @if (ViewBag.Information != null)
            {
        <div class="alert alert-warning"><h4><strong>@TempData["Add-Post"]</strong></h4></div>
    }*@

    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped" style="text-combine-upright:all;">
        <tr style="text-transform: uppercase; text-combine-upright:all;">
            <th>
                <label>Numer Order</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Acceptance Date</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Date of planned completion of the order</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Data finish</label>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 160px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 160px;"></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.ListOrdersUser)
        {

            <tr class="panel panel-primary">
                <td>
                    <h5><strong>Nuber Orders: @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.IdOrder)</strong></h5>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateAccept )
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataPlaningFinish)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataFinish)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show Post Order", "_ListPost", new { idOrder = @item.IdOrder }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoading",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divPosition",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>
                <td>


                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Answer", "_AddPost", new { idZlecenia = @item.IdZlecenia }, new AjaxOptions()
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   LoadingElementId = "divLoadingForm",
                   UpdateTargetId = "divAddPozycje",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

               }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                </td>

            </tr>
            ...
            <tr id="divAddPozycje"></tr>
        }
    </table>

</div>
```

> And PartialView - Form

```
@model AplikacjaHelpDesk.ViewModels.AddPositionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Post";
    Layout = null;
}

<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>




<div class="container-fluid" >
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions()
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "divformResult",
            HttpMethod = "Post"

    }))


    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("IdOrder")
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
                <div class="col-md-10" >
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 ">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-danger" id="formularz"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>

        @*@if (TempData["Add-Post"] != null)
        {

            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <h4><strong>@TempData["Add-Post"];</strong></h4>
            </div>
        }*@


<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        language: "pl",
        theme: "modern",
        fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt 72pt",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
            "textcolor",
            "colorpicker",

        ],
        theme_advanced_fonts: "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n",

        extended_valid_elements: 'i[class]',
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | forecolor backcolor | fontsizeselect"
    });


</script>
```

Comment: You are using `@Ajax.ActionLink`. Your parent View is rendered long before the Partial View is called.

Comment: After writing, the message should appear in asynchronous way without reloading the view.

Comment: Exactly, so you can't access `TempData`.

Comment: What can i use?

Comment: You can return a JSON response from your action method which can have a message and use javascript/jquery to update some div(to show the message) with this message received from the response JSON

Comment: Please, for example, with Json and Jquery. I did not use it yet this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `GET` version of `_AddPost` that returns the `TempData` value:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult _AddPost()
{
    return Json(TempData["Add-Post"]);
}
```

Modify your original `ActionLink` and add an `OnComplete` function:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Answer", "_AddPost", new { idZlecenia = @item.IdZlecenia }, new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST", // Not "GET"
    LoadingElementId = "divLoadingForm",
    UpdateTargetId = "divAddPozycje",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnComplete = "updateMyAlert();" // Add this

}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

Follow that with a new `ActionLink` that updates `my-alert-text` element:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("", "_AddPost", new {}, new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "my-alert-text",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "showMyAlertIfNeeded();"

}, new { id = "update-my-alert-action-link" })
```

Complement the above with relevant HTML and JavaScript:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" id="my-alert" style="display: none;">
    <h4><strong id="my-alert-text"></strong></h4>
</div>
<script>
    function updateMyAlert() {
        document.getElementById("update-my-alert-action-link").click();
    }
    function showMyAlertIfNeeded() {
        var display = document.getElementById("my-alert-text").text ? "" : "none";
        document.getElementById("my-alert").style.display = display;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for improving the impementation in the project and the working.